# navigation stack costmap problem in front of robot

Tags: navigation, husky, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody! I'm trying to use navigation stack on husky. Gmapping works great, pose estimate too but when I'm trying to do a nav goal, and the robot starts moving, in front of it there's always a block of occupied cells in the costmap, when ideed there are no obstacles. Why?
unfortunatly I cannot upload a photo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174037/navigation-stack-costmap-problem-in-front-of-robot/) by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your laser scanner scanning the edges/corners of your robot? I had a problem like this and i decreased the scan angle and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-06-20**:
thanks! I'll try and let you know;)

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-09-06**:
yes It works! :)